# Accessing list-based records from main record

Tags: java, database, jpa

I have a table - let's call it AAA, which has a one-to-many definition to an additional table, assigned BBB. It looks something like that:

```
public class AAA
{
...
   @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="aaa")
   private List<BBB> bbbs;
...
}
```

I want to run a JPA query that will give me all the AAAs that have more than one BBBs, so I used `SIZE(aaa.bbbs)`. However, I want the result set to be ordered by the timestamp of the first bbb in each aaa.

A real-life example: I want to get all my facebook friends, ordered by the latest picture each has added to their profile. AAA in this case is a "Friend", and BBB will be "Picture", and I want to order friends by Picture.CreatedTimestamp.

I basically need to access the first item in the bbbs for each aaa, and order by it. What should be done in order to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need two aggregates over `bbbs` - one to determine the size and another to find the latest timestamp. It can be expressed with `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a
FROM AAA a JOIN a.bbbs b
GROUP BY a.id, a.column1, a.column2
HAVING COUNT(b) > 1
ORDER BY MAX(b.timestamp) DESC
```

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax? The "GROUP BY" won't work in JPA. In MySQL it works but I'm using PostgreSQL and looking for a generic JPA solution...

Comment: @Eldad: `GROUP BY` works in JPA, it's a perfectly valid JPA query.

Comment: Further checking in the JPA documentation, it seems like you're correct, however in practice it won't work (I'm using Hibernate). The exception I'm getting when I try using your query is: "ERROR: column "aaa.some_aaa_column" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function".

Comment: @Eldad: Actually you need to list all columns of `aaa` in `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate, maybe you can use Filters (@Filter and @FilterDef)